# How to handle form submission in HTML5 + Thymeleaf

Tags: html, forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have to submit a form with around 30 input parameters(text, select, datepicker ). The fields are mapped to two classes. How to map each field to get the value in the controller.

HTML:

```
<form id="searchPersonForm" action="#" th:object="${person}" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="person_id" th:field="*{person_id}"></input>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_id" th:field="*{child_id}"></input>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchQuotation(Person person){

    // Some validation
    return "SearchPerson";
    }
```

Person.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "p_id_generator", sequenceName = "PERSON_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "p_id_generator")
    private Long person_id;

    public Long getPerson_id() {
        return person_id;
    }

    public void setPerson_id(Long person_id) {
        this.person_id = person_id;
    }
}
```

Child:java:

```
public class Child { 

    private Long child_id;

    public Long getChild_id() {
        return child_id;
    }

    public void setChild_id(Long child_id) {
        this.child_id = child_id;
    }
}
```

This way I can access person_id from Person object. But how to access child_id.

My application is using HTML5+Thymeleaf with Spring boot.

Can anyone help on this issue. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there could be 2 parts to your question and I will try to answer both.  First on the form itself how would you get to a child_id to display fields from another object on the form.  Since your Person class does not have a Child relationship you would need to have 2 objects.  So if your first controller that served up the form looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setPerson_id((long)3);
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setChild_id((long)4);
    model.put("person", person);
    model.put("child", child);
    return "home";
}
```

Then your form would look like this to show each value from the object.

```
<form id="searchPersonForm" action="/search" th:object="${person}" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="person.person_id" th:field="*{person_id}"></input>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="child.child_id" th:field="${child.child_id}"></input>
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

There is some helpful documentation on the [Thymeleaf site](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax) that explains how the th:object tag interacts with other expressions within the scope.  In this case you would need to reference the child directly using the $ syntax.

On the receiving side you would need to implement a controller to have 2 objects.  As you may notice I changed your form to have an object prefix for the id of the form fields.  So if your controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchQuotation(Person person, Child child){

    System.out.println("person_id=" + person.getPerson_id());
    System.out.println("child_id=" + child.getChild_id());
    // Some validation
    return "SearchPerson";
}
```

you will see the values on the server side.  Let me know if this answers your question.